# PHP session editor

Tags: php, debugging, session

Are there any tools out there that will let me edit the contents of my $_SESSION?  I'm trying to debug a script that is dependant on session state and I'd like to just be able to change the session variables rather than have to change the database, destroy the session and recreate it.  I could probably build an ad-hoc session editor given time, but I don't have time to spare at the moment.

Comment: Great idea for a Open Source Project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code for an extremely basic session editor (yes, found a little time to actually work on one).

```
<?php

function listData (array $data, array $parents = array ())
{
    $output = '';
    $parents    = array_map ('htmlspecialchars', $parents);
    $fieldName  = $parents?
        '[' . implode ('][', $parents) . ']':
        '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $item)
    {
        $isArr  = is_array ($item);
        $output .= $isArr?
            '<li><h4>' . htmlspecialchars ($key) . '</h4>':
            '<li><label>' . htmlspecialchars ($key) . '</label>: ';
        $output .= $isArr?
            '<ul>' . listData ($item, array_merge ($parents, array ($key))) . '</ul>': 
            '<input type="text" name="fields' . $fieldName . '[' . htmlspecialchars ($key) . ']" value="' . htmlspecialchars ($item) . '" />';
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
    return ($output);
}

session_start ();

if ($_POST ['fields'])
{
    $_SESSION   = $_POST ['fields'];
    session_commit ();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Session Editor</title>
<style type="text/css">
label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 8em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: .3em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Session Editor</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>" method="post">
        <ul>
        <?php echo (listData ($_SESSION)); ?>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously extremely simplistic, but it does at least allow me to edit arbitrary session data without having to write new code every time.  Might work some more on this at some point to build it into a fully featured editor, but it will do for now.

Comment: +1 and my thanks because this is exacly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Well the Information in `$_SESSION` is just stored as a serialized string on the disk. (If you don't use something like memcached session storage)

So reading in that file,  unserializing it's contents, changing the appropriate values and then serializing it back should be pretty much everything you need.

---

If you don't want to deal with that you could set the `session_id()` before `session_start()`, then edit the values using php and then call `session_write_close()` to store it on disk again.

---

Sample script for the session id:

```
<?php

session_id("838c4dc18f6535cb90a9c2e0ec92bad4");
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION["a"] = "foo";
session_write_close();
```

Sample script for the unserialisation ([function taken from the comments on the unserialze php.net page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#44837))

```
<?php

session_save_path("./session");

session_start();

$_SESSION["x"] = 1;

$id = session_id();
var_dump($id);

session_write_close();

$session = file_get_contents("./session/sess_$id");

var_dump($session);
function unserialize_session_data( $serialized_string ) {
    $variables = array(  );
    $a = preg_split( "/(\w+)\|/", $serialized_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $a ); $i = $i+2 ) {
        $variables[$a[$i]] = unserialize( $a[$i+1] );
    }
    return( $variables );
}

var_dump(unserialize_session_data($session));
```

Putting it back together isn't hard ether.

Comment: I don't think serializing and unserializing will be necessary, an editor should just be able to session_start, make the changes, then session_commit before doing any actual output.  basic approach looks sound though.

Comment: I've added that for that case that you wanted to to change many sessions and not "session_start/open" each one :)

Comment: That's a good idea, but for now I only need to edit the session that I'm surrently attached to.

Answer (score 2):

To expand it slightly, just adding the ability to add new session vars:

```
<?php

function listData (array $data, array $parents = array ())
{
    $output = '';
    $parents    = array_map ('htmlspecialchars', $parents);
    $fieldName  = $parents?
        '[' . implode ('][', $parents) . ']':
        '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $item)
    {
        $isArr  = is_array ($item);
        $output .= $isArr?
            '<li><h4>' . htmlspecialchars ($key) . '</h4>':
            '<li><label>' . htmlspecialchars ($key) . '</label>: ';
        $output .= $isArr?
            '<ul>' . listData ($item, array_merge ($parents, array ($key))) . '</ul>': 
            '<input type="text" name="fields' . $fieldName . '[' . htmlspecialchars ($key) . ']" value="' . htmlspecialchars ($item) . '" />';
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
    return ($output);
}

session_start ();

if ($_POST ['fields'])
{
    $_SESSION   = $_POST ['fields'];
    session_commit ();
}

if ($_POST['newfield'])
{
    $_SESSION[$_POST['newfield']] = $_POST['newfieldvalue'];
    session_commit ();
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Session Editor</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            min-width: 8em;
            text-align: right;
            padding-right: .3em;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Session Editor</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>" method="post">
            <ul>
                <?php echo (listData($_SESSION)); ?>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
        -------------------------
        <form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>" method="post">
            New Session Var:<input type="text" name="newfield" /><br />
            Session Var Value:<input type="text" name="newfieldvalue" />
            <div>
                <input type="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> any tools out there that will let me edit the contents of my $_SESSION?

```
$_SESSION['var']="whatever value";
```

Comment: That's what I've been doing up till now but it's not exactly a nice way of going about it.

Comment: Having to edit code every time I want to change a session var is a waste of time. It'd be much nicer if I could just start a web app and edit the session in that.

Comment: I can't see how that would be any quicker than just having it open your editor and changing it that way. Maybe saves you having to execute the script in a browser window at a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump( $_SESSION );
```

to see your session

and

```
$_SESSION['variabletoset'] = 'value';
```

to sett your session

You generally want to var_dump the session to see what it is when you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Col. Shrapnel mentions I would simply setup a new PHP script on the same server that looked like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = 'value'; // repeat for every value you need to change
```

Then execute the script every time you need to update the session variables. Just have your app open in one browser tab and the session update script in another. Simple.

I would never bother with tampering in the session temp files myself.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you.  That is the approach I've been using up to now though, and I was just hoping there'd be some open source editor lying around the place that would not require writing new code for every bit of session state I wanted to debug with.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in real-time in your debug session if you are using [PHPEdit](http://www.phpedit.com/en)